# Joining/Union of complex objects

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting, bmesh

So I have two Objects (one is complex sculpted and one imported from an cad stl) I would like to combine for 3D-Printing, therefore it would be great to not have any inner surfaces. But when I combine the two meshes with a boolean union they just overlap and inner surfaces are kept. If I try the same with two speres I get the desired result as you can see in the screenshot [image]

I also tried with triangulated spheres to check if that is the problem but worked like a charm also.

maybe someone has a hint why more complex models won't work.

Here a screenshot of both parts with the boolean active
[image]

Topology of the lower disc (made in cad) that I want to union it with
[image]

Comment: Hi. I think it would be more beneficial to show an image of the meshes that *didn't* join together properly. Thanks.

Comment: Hey :). Just to add - models from cad usually have a *very poor* topology which clashes with Boolean a lot. You may need to clean it first.

Comment: Thats a good hint, because I did manage to intersect the sculpted model with a cylinder quite easy. I hope the screenshot helps to understand. but I also tried remeshing the cad part but no luck with that. Unfortunately I can't upload the whole model because its work related, don't want to get into any problems.